# filename chunk with \includegraphic, graphicx and spaces in the filename

Tags: graphics, xetex, includegraphics, white-space

I'm making a document with `xelatex` and I have a problem.
I include a graphic with `\includegraphic` from the `graphicx` package. My filename **illustration a1-2.png** contain some spaces and when I build my document, my image is properly imported in the pdf, but a remaining part of the filename is printed before the image **a1-2.png a1-2.bb**. I also have the message **LaTeX Warning: File `illustration a1-2.png' not found on input line 7.**

Here's my latex code and the result :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Mesure de formes planes complexes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=12.0cm, keepaspectratio]{illustration a1-2.png}\caption{Polygonisation du contour}\label{Mesure_de_formes_planes_complexes}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thought that graphicx could handle filename with spaces.

I tried the following commands `\includegraphics[..]{{illustration a1-2}.png}`, `\includegraphics[..]{{"illustration a1-2"}.png}` without results.

**Does anyone know where the problem come from and how to include images with spaces in the filename without this buggy thing?**

Comment: do you have a current tex system?

Comment: I'm using TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian and XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999

Comment: quite possible that spaces don't work there yet. The improvements here are quite new.

Comment: recent versions work, I would expect that `\includegraphics[...]{"illustration a1-2"}` works in an old release but otherwise simply rename the file to not have a space (which is good practice anyway)